# Using VSCode, how do I navigate to my robot file when I F12 or command click a python def

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

**Description :** As a user of PyCharm, when I perform a command click of a def, pycharm loads up the robot file that uses that function.

But in VSCode, when I F12 or command click a python def, it does not go to the robot file that has that def used. BUT when I do the reverse, I command click the same function in the Robot File, it navigates to the Python File that has the code.

**VSCode extensions :**

1. Pylance,
2. Python,
3. Robot Code / Robot Framework Language Server

**VSCode Settings.json**

```
{
“python.analysis.extraPaths”: [
“/Users/user/pnut”
],
“python.defaultInterpreterPath”: “/Users/user/.pyenv/shims/python”
}
```